# How to render a video with audio in Blender 2.80?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

When choosing AVI JPEG, the resulting video won’t have audio.
And when choosing FFmpeg video it only renders a black image file.
Can someone say how to have audio with AVI JPEG, or how to render an actual video file with FFmpeg video?

Thanks guys

Comment: You should probably edit your title as the obvious answer to the question in the title is Render > Render Animation or Ctrl+F12.

Comment: That's exactly how I end up with an audio-less video file when choosing AVI JPEG, and a black image file when choosing FFmpeg video (by just Render > Render Animation or Ctrl+F12). 
Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Yes, I know that isn't the right answer which is why I suggested to change your title to be more specific.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. HOWEVER, am I also to infer from your information that it's all in the title, and the content of the post has "no importance whatsoever"? If so, I guess I had not needed a post message after all, just a title. Back to your point: maybe my title should be the same plus "...in detail step by step". Or what would you suggest?

Comment: "Either no audio or black video when rendering in Blender 2.8"

Comment: I suspected that the audio may not be encoded by default because of the Eevee render engine in 2.8... Trying to follow up on this answer/suspicion, but the encoding section in the properties pane doesn't exist for me. I can't find it in 2.8. Have you guys found a clean solution? Though not a full answer, I hope that my contribution is worth something. DrPepperCan, could you please elaborate on your timing effect strip temporary solution? How did you add an effect strip to an audio strip? My blender says it can't put an effect on a sound clip. (Sorry; I would reply directly but I need 50 "reput

Answer (score 0):

I added a Speed Control effect modifier, and I synched the audio and the video strips, and that seemed to have done the trick. Now the video is rendering.

Comment: Could you please be more specific regarding the solution? How did you synch the strips? Is that always necessary? Can changing the audio bitrate to the source video clip's bitrate cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

OK so essentially, to render with audio, you will want the settings to be as follows:

**For transparent videos:**

File Format: FFmpeg video

Color: RGBA

Container: Quicktime

Video Codec: QT Animation

Audio Codec: AAC

[image]

**For non-transparent videos:**

File Format: FFmpeg video

Color: RGB

Container: MPEG-4

Video Codec: H.264

Audio Codec: MP3 (OR AAC)

[image]

If you are a more visual learner, this video may be for you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dV0hCn04d9M